# Driver throws timeout exception when I navigate to page using URL, because I'm being redirected to another page with password protection

Tags: c#, selenium, redirect, selenium-chromedriver, timeoutexception

This is a login problem. The project I'm working at is secured through a federation server. So, basically when I use `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(someUrl)`. I'm being redirected to a page that is not 'someUrl' and I'm requested userName and password at the redirected page. Problem is that my line of code where I navigate to 'someUrl' times out and I cannot complete authorization on the redirected page.
Another problem is that redirected page URL contains guides which I'm unable to get. So the best solution to my problem would be to ignore the exception that driver throws when he tries to reach 'someUrl' and then I just continue with `alert.SwithTo()` or `http//:username:password@url.com` solution

I've tried completing this through with `try catch` block, where I would catch the exception but continue execution in the catch block, but that doesn't work.

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("someUrl");

var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("UserName","Password");
alert.Accept();
```

threw exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:444/session/6778bv57v8vb88c8576/alert/text timed out after 10 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

Comment: Is the password prompt an actual browser prompt, or a separate web page with username and password fields?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code for passing username and password as parameter inside the url. After that you won't need switch to the alert, `SetAuthenticationCredentials()` and accept it:

```
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://" + username + ":" + password + "@<site-needing-auth>.com")
```

Comment: that is the other solution that i've tied. Problem is when i do navigate().gotourl(url), even if i include username and password as a parameter it doesn't work, because this is not page when username and password are needed. I need to set username and password to url i am being redirected to, and that url is dynamic and can't set to point at it directly because i don't know what he's going to look like. So if i manage to pass step 'Navigate().GoToUrl("MyApplicationUrl"), i will then easy get the string of url i was redirected to and send username and password. But i can't pass due to timeout.

Comment: @ИлијаСмиљанић Try to add this : driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

Comment: try to set time out more than 10 seconds before get the url in a try catch block and after that set the timeout 10 seconds again. @ИлијаСмиљанић